# Unable to .getKey() after .add() to Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am migrating from Firebase Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore. Previously, I would `.push()` under the Realtime Database, and I would get the key of the `.push()` as follows:

```
final String key = mBaseRef.child("ABC").push().getKey();
```

It does not appear this method is available under the new Cloud Firestore. I am trying as such:

```
mStoreBaseRef.collection("ABC").add(pollMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
        String key = String.valueOf(mStoreBaseRef.collection("ABC").document().getId());
        Log.v("KEY", key);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The log simply is not returning the key that was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference to the added document is returned as the result of the completion task.  The document ID is available from it:

```
    mStoreBaseRef.collection("ABC").add(pollMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentReference docRef = task.getResult();
                String key = docRef.getId();
                Log.v("KEY", key);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Much appreciated brotha

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
final String key = mBaseRef.child("ABC").push().getKey();
```

with

```
DocumentReference key = db.collection("ABC").document();
```

This will return the auto-generated ID.
You can then reference it later as:

```
key.set(data);
```

Or you can get the Firebase push ID as:

```
key.getId();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the **Id** by this code

```
 db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
 String documentId=db.collection("MyCollection").document().getId();
```

and when you want to to set value for this  document

```
db.collection("MyCollection").document(documentId).set(myDataObject);
```